# Teamviewer chat history

Tags: teamviewer

I am using Teamviewer for a while.

Can we enable auto saving of chat messages?

I checked in options but didnt find anything there.

If it saves chat messages by default,where is the location of the chat history file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't because all conversations between peers are deemed private. It is under their security policy to conceal and protect all kinds of confidential information from public knowledge.

All logs file of TeamViewer locate at C:\Users\"Your_Name"\AppData\Roaming\TeamViewer
and C:\Program Files\TeamViewer\VersionX (X is version number. My PC installed version 9).

Comment: so what do the buttons "delete conversation" and "delete history" do? Under the gear icon in the chat window.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think TeamViewer kept separate Chat History. If you recorded your session, then you will be able to see everything (including the Chat). But not chat on its own.